# will react native ios simulator throw an error if https request is not secure? (certificate is invalid)

Tags: javascript, react-native, networking, request, fetch

I'm making a client app with react native and my server-side is using express
I've gotten the network requests to work in my google chrome browser to my API.
Although, please note that the page is not secure because the certificate is not valid.
I've been trying again and again to make this same request with my react native app (to the same exact URL) but I keep getting the error "Network request failed". I've researched and tried several different things, like changing from localhost to IP, but I can't solve this. Remember, it IS an https request and it DOES work in my browser as long as I flag the message to proceed to an unsecured connection. Fetch looks something like this:

```
fetch(`https://192.168.72.32:9000/search?v=${data.search}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
            //this.setVerb(data);
                
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

Also note that when I use this request to a random API url like so: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", it did work.
Could it be that react native won't fulfill my network request due to the fact that it isn't a secure connection?

Answer (score 0):

solved:
react native will deny any web request that comes from an unsecured source
solution:
ill be using HTTP without App Transport Security in the meantime until it's time for deployment